# Convert String to Big Decimal

Tags: talend

I have a value (surv_amount) which is currently a string within the database. I need to convert it from a string to a big decimal in TMap. I have tried new BigDecimal(surv_amount) but get this error message:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "schema_talendStats_DB" is null

Any idea how I would resolve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`Relational.ISNULL(row1.surv_amount)? new BigDecimal("0.0") : new BigDecimal(row1.surv_amount)`